# why am i not able to declare sigset_t with std=c99?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

If i compile the below program with std=c99, i get an error, but the program compiles fine without the c99 flag. Why?

```
#include <signal.h>
void x()
{
    sigset_t dd;
}

int main(void)
{
    x();
    return 0;
}


jim@cola temp]$ gcc -std=c99 blah.c -o blah
blah.c: In function ‘x’:
blah.c:9: error: ‘sigset_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
blah.c:9: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
blah.c:9: error: for each function it appears in.)
blah.c:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘dd’
```

Comment: it requires `_GNU_SOURCE` to compile this with C99 standard.  Try with `gcc -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE blah.c -o blah` instead.

Comment: @user9000 Why bother with `-std=c99` then? Just use `gcc -std=gnu99` and be done.

Comment: @melpomene what does that has to do with it?  `_GNU_SOURCE` makes some GNU extensions available.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice you said gnu, thought it was 89 ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sigset_t` is not part of `<signal.h>` in standard C and you requested strict standards compatibility with `-std=c99`. That is, a strictly standard C program can do:

```
#include <signal.h>

int sigset_t;
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

and expect it to work.

Comment: So, what would be the counterpart of sigset_t in c99?

Comment: ... nothing? Why do you assume such a thing exists in standard C?

Comment: if you can't find `sigset_t` then define it yourself like in the code below. it is just an `unsigned long`

Comment: @Aniket That is terrible advice.

Comment: @melpomene so if i want to use signals specifc functions like sigprocmask and would like c99 features like restrict, what flag should i pass to gcc?

Comment: @user9000 Is that same as #define _GNU_SOURCE ?

Answer (score 2):

`sigset_t` is not in C99 standard, but it is available in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html). You can define `_POSIX_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to make `sigset_t` available.

Here is the definition:

```
#define _NSIG 64 
#define _NSIG_BPW 32 
#define _NSIG_WORDS (_NSIG / _NSIG_BPW) 

typedef unsigned long old_sigset_t; /* at least 32 bits */ 

typedef struct { 
unsigned long sig[_NSIG_WORDS]; 
} sigset_t;
```

Also see [What does #define _POSIX_SOURCE mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48332332/608639)