# What does #define _POSIX_SOURCE mean?

Tags: c, macros, posix

What advantages does using `#define _POSIX_SOURCE` in C confer to my program? Can I access more libraries in my program or I can call some functions which are present directly in C. What is this macro used for?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948661/what-does-the-flag-d-posix-c-source-200112l-mean/36264825#36264825

Answer (score 26):

It allows you to use functions that are not part of the standard C library but are part of the POSIX.1 (IEEE Standard 1003.1) standard. Using the macros described in
[feature_test_macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) allows you to control the definitions exposed
by the system header files.

As far as I know `_POSIX_SOURCE` is obsolete and you should use `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` instead.

For example, if you want to use [`strndup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strndup), you have to use

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

See also

- [1.3.4 Feature Test Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html)
- [5.12 Posix Variants](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Posix-Variants.html)
- [man 7 feature_test_macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)

Comment: If you are working on Linux with GCC, then by default it works in `-std=gnu11` or `-std=gnu90` mode, and the POSIX (and some other) sets of symbols are made visible without you needing to set `_XOPEN_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` or other similar macros. If you use `-std=c11` or `-std=c99` or (perish the thought) `-std=c90`, then POSIX and GNU symbols are not available by default; you have to define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to see the POSIX symbols.