# implicit declaration of function 'getline' even thought it is

Tags: c, compiler-errors, getline

I'm currently having some problems with getline() in c.
I know it's not a standard C function, however I am using the proper resources according to what I've seen online.

I have both:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

However I am still having problems compiling, it gives me this output:

```
main.c: In function 'read-file':
main.c:46:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getline' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
C:\Users\Miguel\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6aYESe.o:main.c:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `getline'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, I've seen several problems like this, however no solution seems to apply.

Comment: You're on a Windows machine; are you using MinGW or Cygwin or something else?  If you're using MinGW, it may well not be defined — it is a Minimal GNU for Windows.  You could try requesting POSIX support (`#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` for example), but if `_GNU_SOURCE` doesn't work, the chances are that POSIX won't either. I don't often suggest this, but try either disabling the warning (change the compiler options), or include a declaration (`ssize_t getline(char ** restrict linep, size_t * restrict linecapp, FILE * restrict stream);`) in the code, and see whether it links.  It may not.

Comment: In fact, given that you get an 'undefined reference to `getline`' message, the function is not defined in your environment.  You will need to provide your own implementation — it isn't hard to write.  Or you can contact me at a pinch; see my profile.

Comment: Or see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47229318/918959

Answer (score 0):

try with the following preprocessor sentence:
`#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`

"It allows you to use functions that are not part of the standard C library but are part of the POSIX.1 (IEEE Standard 1003.1) standard. Using the macros described in feature_test_macros allows you to control the definitions exposed by the system header files."

ref: [What does #define _POSIX_SOURCE mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332332/what-does-define-posix-source-mean)